# Changing the rate at which a method is called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm still new to Objective C, and I feel this might be a probably a basic concept I don't know.

I'm working with OpenGL and I have the method GLKView of the viewcontroller, is called when "the view needs to be updated". From this method, I call another method, but I don't want the second method to be called at a rate that I specify.

How would I go about accomplishing this? I understand that viewcontroller.preferredFramesPerSecond can be set, but I only want this ONE specific method to work on a different timer..

Is this even the right way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to use NSTimer